# RelativeLayout align parent bottom does not align at bottom

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a custom circular layout using a relative layout:

```
public class CircularLayout extends RelativeLayout implements OnDragListener {
    private DropCallback onDrop = null;
    private ImageButton imageButton = null;
    private ImageView imageViewBackgroundWave = null;
    private int radius = -1;
    private double step = -1;
    private double angle = -1;
    private static final int CENTER_ID = 111;

    public CircularLayout(Context context, DropCallback onDrop, int radius, List<View> views) {
        super(context);

        this.onDrop = onDrop;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.step = (2 * Math.PI) / views.size();

        this.initView(context, views);
    }

    private void initView(Context context, List<View> views) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsView);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsImageview = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParamsImageview.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        layoutParamsImageview.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        this.imageViewBackgroundWave = new ImageView(this.getContext());
        this.imageViewBackgroundWave.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsImageview);
        this.imageViewBackgroundWave.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_wave));

        this.addView(this.imageViewBackgroundWave);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        this.imageButton = new ImageButton(context);
        this.imageButton.setId(CENTER_ID);
        this.imageButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        this.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_power_on);
        this.imageButton.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
        this.imageButton.setOnDragListener(this);

        this.addView(this.imageButton);

        for(View view : views) {
            this.addView(this.placeView(view));
        }
    }

    private View placeView(View view) {
        view.measure(0, 0);
        this.imageButton.measure(0, 0);

        int x = (int)((view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2) + this.radius * Math.cos(this.angle));
        int y = (int)((view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2) + this.radius * Math.sin(this.angle));

        this.angle += this.step;

        int deltaX = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        int deltaY = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        int deltaImageX = this.imageButton.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        int deltaImageY = this.imageButton.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        int xToDraw = ((x - deltaX) - deltaImageX);
        int yToDraw = ((y - deltaY) - deltaImageY);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, CENTER_ID);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, CENTER_ID);
        layoutParams.setMargins(xToDraw, 0, 0, yToDraw);

        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
        return this.onDrop.onDrop(view, event);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the imageview (imageViewBackgroundWave) is not aligning at the bottom. It aligns a little bit higher:

[image]

So the question is: how can I align my imageview to the bottom of the screen?
The image is exactly as high and as wide as the blue stripe. there is no 
padding or white color in it. Its just the blue stripe shown in the picture above.

EDIT:

The background_wave.png:

[image]

I use this custom layout in my `MenuFragment` and call it with the following code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ... init the imagebuttons in the list of views

    this.circleView = new CircularLayout(this.getActivity(), this, 250, views);
    this.circleView.setOnDragListener(this);
    this.circleView.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));

    return this.circleView;
}
```

Comment: Does this work? `this.addView(this.imageView, layoutParamsImageview)` (remove the `this.imageView.setLayoutParams()` call as well)

Comment: that does not change anything. ofcourse not. in addView also imageView.setLayoutParams() is called.

Comment: Is the parent view of your custom view a RelativeLayout that takes up the entire screen?

Comment: The custom layout i mentioned is the top view. it takes the entire screen because i set height and width to "match_parent"

Comment: Could you attach your `R.drawable.background_wave`?

Comment: yes. i updated my post and added the background_wave.png

Comment: As for now, this doesn't make any sense. There is no reason why that view is 112px above the nav bar. You should post some more layout-related code (e.g., when you call that method, ecc)

Comment: Ok i edited my post. i posted the whole custom layout (CircularLayout) and also the onCreateView method where i set the CircularLayout to my MenuFragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the ImageView to stick to the bottom by adding this line of code:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_END);
```

The reason for the weirdness is that the ImageView bounds are calculated by the layout engine first, *then* the image inside the ImageView is scaled to fit the allocated area according to the scale type.

Using WRAP_CONTENT for the ImageView allocates an area based on the size of the *unscaled* image bitmap - even if it is larger than the screen. Your background_wave.png file is wider than the screen, so a larger area than is needed is allocated. Then afterwards when the image gets fitted inside the layout area using FIT_CENTER it gets shrunk down and centered, so you end up up with white space above and below it.

You can verify this by resizing your background_wave.png to be 1/4 the size: it should align the bottom even without the above code change.

Answer (score -1):

You are setting width and height twice with `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` and `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM`

Try this:

```
private void initView(Context context) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    this.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsImageview = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    this.imageView = new ImageView(this.getContext());
    this.imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsImageview);
    this.imageView.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_wave));

    this.addView(this.imageView);
}
```

I also recommend you to use visual designer with XML to test layout's rules and parameters, then, if you need it, you can set that rules in code to get the same result.

Comment: Ehm.... i dont get your answer because this makes it even worse. the position of the image is now at the center of the screen.